# Normalizing Nmap Results from File with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

What I am trying to achieve is the following:

Step 1: Scan the Target IP Address with the following `nmap` command:

```
nmap_scan_command = f"nmap -p- -sC -sV -oG output.txt {target}"

result = subprocess.run(nmap_scan_command, shell=True, check=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
```

the `result` temp could contain the following text:

```
Host: 192.168.0.1 ()     Status: Up
Host: 192.168.0.1 ()     22/open/tcp//tcpwrapped///, 80/open/tcp//tcpwrapped///, 443/open/tcp//ssl|http//Golang net|http server (Go-IPFS json-rpc or InfluxDB API)/, 5671/open/tcp//http//Golang net|http server (Go-IPFS json-rpc or InfluxDB API)/, 49363/open/tcp///// Ignored State: filtered (65530) # Nmap done at Mon Jul 31 16:14:16 2023 -- 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 551.90 seconds
```

Step 2: Parse the results and extract open ports and running services on them so I can save them to a dictionary:

```
grep_command = "grep -E '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}' output.txt"
result2 = subprocess.run(grep_command, shell=True, check=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
```

With the above command in Step 2, I can get the lines that contain IPs, but how to separate open ports for each IP and store them in a dictionary for further processing?

Maybe on the `result2` temp contains results for more than one IP address. I am pretty sure that could be a one-liner command for this but I am not able on how to achieve this...

Comment: You certainly don't need to run an external command for grep, you can use python's `re` library

Comment: Can you show us what `nmap_scan_command` looks like?

Comment: @Paolo see below:
Host: 192.168.0.1 ()     Status: Up
Host: 192.168.0.1 ()     Ports: 22/open/tcp//tcpwrapped///, 80/open/tcp//tcpwrapped///, 443/open/tcp//ssl|http//Golang net|http server (Go-IPFS json-rpc or InfluxDB API)/, 5671/open/tcp//http//Golang net|http server (Go-IPFS json-rpc or InfluxDB API)/, 49363/open/tcp/////      Ignored State: filtered (65530)
# Nmap done at Mon Jul 31 16:14:16 2023 -- 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 551.90 seconds

Comment: Add that to the question body

Comment: @Paolo I have updated the result temp as I missed to copy the IP address